# Google API in Colab invalid request

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the google API on my Colab notebook.  I was following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gsuite-apis-intro/#0) but it seems to be out of date.

I ended up following [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/kmcentush/site/blob/master/_notebooks/2020-08-16-fastapi_google_oauth_part1.ipynb#scrollTo=RlK2EGpAnlfW)  to know how to make my OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

but when I run my code  and I click on the link I am getting this error :
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue.

here is my code :

```
!pip install httpx
!pip install starlette
!pip install fastapi

from typing import Optional
import os
from starlette.requests import Request
from fastapi import FastAPI
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these SCOPES, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def get_authenticated_service():
 creds = None
 if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
 if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
     creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
     flow =InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('/content/client_secret_99.apps.googleusercontent.com.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

  try:
   service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
   return service
  except HttpError as error:
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
    return None

 def list_drive_files(service, orderBy='modifiedByMeTime desc', pageSize=5):
  results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=pageSize, orderBy=orderBy, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
     print(f"{item['name']} ({item['mimeType']})")

 if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
  service = get_authenticated_service()
  list_drive_files(service, orderBy='modifiedByMeTime desc', pageSize=5)
```

So what I am missing ?